# Text formatting error: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier

Tags: python, string-formatting

What does `'=' alignment` mean in the following error message, and why does this code cause it?

```python
>>> "{num:03}".format(num="1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier
```

The code has a subtle problem: the input value `"1"` is text, not a number. But the error message doesn't appear to have anything to do with that.

Nothing in the error message indicates why “'=' alignment” is relevant,
and it does not appear in the code. So what is the significance of emitting that error message?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### Python 3.10 and later

This issue is [corrected in Python 3.10 and later](https://docs.python.org/release/3.10.0/whatsnew/changelog.html#id70):

> In string formatting, preceding the width field by '0' no longer affects the default alignment for strings.

The example code no longer raises an error; instead, it gives the result `'100'` because the default `align` for non-numeric types is `<`.

### Python earlier than 3.10

The error message occurs because `'=' alignment` has been implied by the format specifier.

The `str.format` [format spec mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) parser has decided on the
alignment specifier “=” because:

> Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables
> sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a
> fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='.

So by specifying `0N` as the “zero-padding to N width”, you have implied both “the input is a numeric type”, and “the zeros should go between the sign and the digits”. That latter implication is what is meant by `'=' alignment`.

Since the value `"1"` is not numeric, the “=”-alignment handling code raises that exception. The message is written expecting you know what it's talking about because you requested (by implication) the “=” alignment.

Yes, I think that error message needs to be improved. <s>I've [raised an issue for that](http://bugs.python.org/issue27772).</s> Thanks to Serhiy Storchaka for [fixing this issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11270)! [Python 3.10 includes this change](https://docs.python.org/release/3.10.0/whatsnew/changelog.html#id70).

Answer (score 40):

A workaround is to use `'>'` (right justify) padding, which is with the syntax:

```
[[fill]align][width]
```

with  align being `>`, fill being `0` and width being `3`.

```
>>> "{num:0>3}".format(num="1")
'001'
```

The problem was that there is a different `0` in the format specification:

> ```
> format_spec     ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][grouping_option][.precision][type]
> #                                          ^^^ This one
> ```

That zero just makes `fill` default to `0` and `align` to `=`.

`=` alignment is specified as:

> Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’. This alignment option is only valid for numeric types. It becomes the default when ‘0’ immediately precedes the field width.

[Source (Python 3 docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-align)

This expects the argument to be an `int`, as strings don't have signs. So we just manually set it to the normal default of `>` (right justify).

Also note that `0` just specifies the default values for `fill` and `align`. You can change both or just the align.

```
>>> # fill defaults to '0', align is '>', `0` is set, width is `3`
>>> "{num:>03}".format(num=-1)
'0-1'
>>> # fill is `x`, align is '>', `0` is set (but does nothing), width is `"3"`
>>> "{num:x>03}".format(num=-1)
'x-1'
>>> # fill is `x`, align is '>', `0` is set (but does nothing), width is `"03"` (3)
>>> "{num:x>003}".format(num=-1)
'x-1'
```

Answer (score 12):

`str.__format__` doesn't know what to do with your `03` part. That only works with numbers:

```
>>> "{num:03}".format(num=1)
'001'
```

If you actually want to zero-pad a string, you can use `rjust`:

```
>>> "1".rjust(3, "0")
'001'
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was trying to zero-pad a *string* instead of a number.

The solution was simply to convert the text to a number before applying the padding:

```py
num_as_text = '23'
num_as_num = int(num_as_text)
padded_text = f'{num_as_num:03}'
```

Comment: This is the simplest method - you can condense to one line with `f'{int(num_as_text):03}'` - switching the string to a int for padding. You could probably take it farther and switch it back to a string if needed.

Answer (score 2):

> [Changed in version 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language): Preceding the width field by '0' no longer affects the default
> alignment for strings.

[Thanks to  Serhiy Storchaka for fixing it](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11270/files).

The OP's code sample runs fine in Python 3.10+. However note that it returns `100` because the default `align` for non-numeric types is `<`.

For older Python versions manually add the left alignment character: `"{num:<03}".format(num="1")`

Comment: Thank you for this update. I have edited the accepted answer to include this relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert 'string->"1" where a float->3.44 is required. Remove the quotes "1", i.e. num=1, and it will work

Answer (score -1):

Just for others who google searched and found this Q&A.

This error:

```bash
    out_name = track_name_fmt.format(track, song)
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier
```

Was fixed by using:

```py
out_name = track_name_fmt.format(int(track), song)
```

Forcing `track` to integer solved the problem.

Comment: This is an answer to a somewhat different question; it doesn't constitute an answer to this question.

Comment: @bignose It's an answer to the error message that might help others who use Google Search Engine. However I despise down votes and will delete answer soon.

Answer (score -4):

This format would be acceptable

```
"{num}:03".format(num="1")
```

but the way you have the placeholder specified `{num:03}` is not. That is an interesting ValueError though, if you remove the `:` the interesting error is replaced by a standard `KeyError`.

Comment: This doesn't do what OP was intending. They want to left-align a padded string using `format`.

Comment: Ah ok I see now. That makes more sense.