# ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm doing a little program to visualize a chaotic function with 2 numbers and the iteration count as input.

While formatting the prints, I'm running into the error stated in the title

I tried using the {:^n} tag to specify the width to be taken up and make the printed value centered inside that width

```
def main():

    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x = float(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
    y = float(input("Enter another number between 0 and 1: "))
    n = int(input("How many iterations do you want to see?: "))

    print(("{0:0}{1:^9f}{2:^9f}").format("index", x, y))
    print("_" * 23)

    for i in range(n):
        x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
        y = 3.9 * y * (1 - y)
        print(("{0:^5}{1:^9}{2:^9}").format(range(n).index(i) + 1, x, y))


Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\chaos.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\chaos.py", line 10, in main
    print(("{0:0}{1:^9f}{2:^9f}").format("index", x, y))
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier
```

The output should be a nicely formatted table.

Comment: that may help [Text formatting error: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044676/text-formatting-error-alignment-not-allowed-in-string-format-specifier)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to format a string `"index"` with `":0"`, change to something like `"^10"` and it'll at least run:

`print(("{0:^10}{1:^9f}{2:^9f}").format("index", x, y))`

Comment: Well, but I got it to work with 0:5, I wonder why. Doesn't :0 just mean "take as much space as you need?"

So what you're saying is i should use 0^10?